# Split a string into key-value pairs and use them to set environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a string like this stored in an env var:

```
$ echo $PARAMS 
LOGGING=s3 ARGS="-foo bar -port 80" HELLO=world
```

I would like to split this string and use it to set independent env. vars such that I would end up with:

```
$ env
LOGGING=s3
ARGS="-foo bar -port 80"
HELLO=world
```

I need to do this within the constraints of a CI system, so ideally just some `bash`.

Comment: No change should be necessary?

Comment: @PaulHodges not sure what you're implying? I need those individual env. vars set, which they're currently not set.

Comment: Is it easy/possible to change value of $PARAMS to comma-seperated like LOGGING=s3,ARGS="-foo bar -port 80",HELLO=world ?

Comment: @congbaoguier yes, I could change that to comma-separated instead of space-separated. is your idea to use IFS?

Comment: What I meant was that you should not need to split the string if it is properly formatted. It will work as-is with them all on the same line if executed in your current env, as Glenn suggested with `eval`, or as I suggested by writing to a file and sourcing it. Parsing the string is difficult since one of the vars has embedded spaces. It can still be done, but simpler solutions are more stable than trying to implement a grammar.

Comment: @AlexKaskasoli yes

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```sh
$ eval "$PARAMS"
$ export $(grep -Po '\w+(?==)' <<< "$PARAMS")
```

then

```sh
$ env | grep -e LOGGING -e ARGS -e HELLO
HELLO=world
ARGS=-foo bar -port 80
LOGGING=s3
```

That requires GNU grep for `-P`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. Could you explain this a bit? I'm not sure I get why eval is here.

Comment: `eval` executes its argument as code in the current shell. Before eval, $PARAMS is just a string containing characters. After eval, the variables have been declared in the current shell, but are not (yet) *environment* variables..

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use a tempfile.

```
$: f=$(mktemp); echo "export $PARAMS">"$f"; . "$f"; echo "[$LOGGING] [$ARGS] [$HELLO]"; sh -c 'echo "$ARGS"'
[s3] [-foo bar -port 80] [world]
-foo bar -port 80
```

To elaborate -

```
f=$(mktemp)                         # create a unique tempfile
echo "export $PARAMS" > "$f"        # write the declaration to the temp
. "$f"                              # source the tempfile into the current env, creating the vars
echo "[$LOGGING] [$ARGS] [$HELLO]"  # show that they are set
sh -c 'echo "$ARGS"'                # verify that they are exported
```